# Why are onOpen and onClose Streams (not Futures) in dart:html WebSockets?

Tags: dart, dart-html

A [`dart:html.WebSocket`](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:html.WebSocket#id_onClose) opens once and closes once. So I'd expect that the `onOpen` and `onClose` properties would be Futures, but in reality they are Streams.

Of course, I can use `stream.onClose.first` to get a Future. But the `done` property on the `dart:io` version of [WebSocket](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart:io.WebSocket#id_done) is a Future as expected, so I'm wondering if I'm missing something.

Why use Streams and not Futures in `dart:html`?

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps they can send multiple errors, a Future can only provide one error.

Comment: Maybe because they are events in JavaScript DOM were something like a one shot event doesn't exist (now we have Promises/Futures in JS, too!). The Dart code is generated from the DOM definiton and all events are translated into streams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a word: **transparency**. The purpose of the `dart:html` package is to provide access to the DOM of the page, and so it mirrors the underlying DOM constructs as closely as possible. This is in contrast with `dart:io` where the goal is to provide a convenient server-side API rather than exposing some underlying layer.

Sure, as a consumer of the API you would expect `open` and `close` to be fired only once, whereas `message` would be fired multiple times, but at the root of things, `open`, `close`, `message`, and `error` are [all just events](http://www.w3.org/TR/websockets/#handler-websocket-onopen). And in `dart:html`, DOM events are modeled as streams.

And actually, a WebSocket *could* very well fire multiple open events (or close events). The following is definitely a contrived example, but consider this snippet of javascript:

```js
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://mysite.com');
socket.dispatchEvent(new Event('open'));
socket.dispatchEvent(new Event('open'));
socket.dispatchEvent(new Event('open'));
```

How would a Dart WebSocket object behave in a situation like this, if `onOpen` were a Future rather than a Stream? Of course I highly, *highly* doubt this would ever surface out there in the "real world". But the DOM allows for it, and `dart:html` should not be making judgment calls trying to determine which situations are likely and which are not. If it's possible according to the spec, `dart:html` should reflect that. Its role is simply to pass through the behavior - as transparently as possible - and let the consumer of the API decide what cases they need to handle and which they can ignore.